# MongoDB C# Driver Generic Types

Tags: c#, mongodb, generics

I'm trying to add generic objects to mongodb

how can I have some thing like this works?

if I must implement my own serializer, may you give me some hints, where can I start?

```
public class  ParameterBase{}
[BsonDiscriminator(RootClass = true, Required = true)]
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(NumericParameter))]
public class Parameter<T> : ParameterBase
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{get;set;}

    public virtual Type Type { get{return typeof(T); } }      
    public virtual T Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(_value, value) == false)
            {
                _value = value;
            }
        }
    }
    protected T _value;       
}

public class NumericParameter : Parameter<double>
{
    private double _value;
    public double Value{get{return _value;}set{_value = value;}}
}

public class StringParameter : Parameter<string>
{
    private string _value;
    public string Value{get{return _value;}set{_value = value;}}
}
```

the problem is
when I try to add NumericParameter like this

```
var context = new DatabaseContext("test");
        var collection = context.db.GetCollection<ParameterBase>("RecipeParameterSet");
        var nParameter = new NumericParameter()
        {
            Name = "Offset",
            Value = 1.8
        };
        collection.InsertOne(nParameter);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

this Code insert this document in the database

```json
{
"_id":{"$oid":"000000000000000000000000"},
"_t":["Parameter`1","NumericParameter"],
"Name":"Offset",
"Value":1.8
}
```

and if I add the class StringParameter to the BsonKnownTypes of the class
Parameter
like this
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(NumericParameter), typeof(StringParameter))]

I get this error

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Class Ha.MongoDb.Playground.StringParameter cannot be assigned to Class Ha.MongoDb.Playground.Parameter`1[[System.Double, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].  Ensure that known types are derived from the mapped class.
> Parametername: type'

Comment: Can you explain what the problem you're experiencing is with the current code? It's always a good starting point...

Comment: sorry for that, I added more informations and I hope you can help.

Comment: Do you need the discriminator and known types?